# What is the time complexity (big-O) of the following code? It is hard to analyze

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```cpp
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
    for (int k = j * j; k < n; k++) {
      ++cnt;
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea of it.
How to analyze the time complexity of it?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that the code is Omega(n²) (that is, is at *least* quadratic) - the two outer loops execute around n²/2 times.

The inner `k` loop executes zero times unless `j` is less than `sqrt(n)`. Even though it executes zero times, it takes some computation to compute the conditions for the loop, so it's O(1) work in these cases.

When `j` is less than `sqrt(n)`, `i` must also be less than `sqrt(n)`, since by the construction of the loops, `j` is always greater than or equal to `i`. In these cases, the `k` loop does n-j² iterations. We can construct a bound for the total amount of work in this inner loop in these cases: both i and j are less than sqrt(n), and there's at worst O(n) work done in the k loop, so there's at most O(n²) (ie: sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) * n) total work done in the inner loop.

There's also at most O(n²) total work done for the cases where the inner loop is trivial (ie: when j>sqrt(n)).

This gives a proof that the runtime complexity of the code is θ(n²).

Methods involving looking at nested loops individually and constructing big-O bounds for them do not in general give tight bounds, and this is an example question where such a method fails.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach would be to look at the loops separately, meaning that we have three O(.) that are connected by a product. Hence,

Complexity of the Algorithm = O(OuterLoop)*O(MiddleLoop)*O(InnerLoop)

Now look at each loop separately:

Outerloop: This is the most simple one. Incrementing from 1 to n, resulting in O(n)

Middleloop: This is non-obvious, the terminate condition of the loop is still n, but the starting iterator value is i, meaning that the larger i gets, less time it will take to finish the loop. But this factor is quadratical-asymptotically only a constant, meaning that it is still O(n), hence O(n^2) "until" the second loop.

Inner loop: We see, that the iterator increases quadratically. But we also see that the quadratic-increasing depends on the second loop, which we said to be O(n). Since, we again only look at the complexity asymptomatically, means that we can assume that j rises linearly, and since k rises quadratically until n, it will take \square(n) iterations until n is reached. Meaning that the inner most loop has a running time of O(\square(n)).

Putting all these results together,

O(n * n* square(n))=O(n^2*square(n))

Comment: n^2*square(n) can't be simplified as n !!!! Total complexity is O(n^2.5) (O(n^2*sqrt(n)).

Comment: yah that is true, I have overseen it

Comment: The inner loop is O(1) for j>sqrt (n). The inner loop is at worst O(n) for j<sqrt(n). Putting that together with j>i, it's possible to bound the total runtime by O(n^2) and it's clear this must be a tight bound. The reasoning in the answer is not mathematically sound.

Comment: I do not understand the inner loop. Its increasing step is 1 (just from j^2 to n). So why its time complexity is O(square(n))?